# how do I get calendar_id from Google Calendar API

Tags: ruby, google-calendar-api

I know you can get it on the settings page.
I have multiple calendars on a single account.

I can get the names back with 
service.list_calendar_lists(page_token: page_token)

but how do I can the calendar ids associated with the names of the calendars

Answer (score 0):

The structure that's returned from `service.list_calendar_lists` is a JSON that has an entry `items`

`items` is an array of calendar list items, and each array element includes `id` which is what you're asking for.

So something like

```
array_of_ids = service.list_calendar_lists(page_token: page_token)['items']map{|i| i['id']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CalendarList() with a GET request as shown in the Google Calendar API [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/get). I tested this by retrieving my own calendar id by passing in the "primary" keyword as described in the documentation linked above.